# Jar Runnable with external library - Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have created a small program using Java and openCV. Now I want to export this to Runnable Jar. Is there a way for me to make Runnable Jar with Java and openCV library using Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

In order to include native libraries in an executable java program you need to specify it at the moment of executing a jar. For example:

```
java -Djava.library.path="<path_to_opencv>/opencv/build/lib" -jar FaceDetection.jar
```